# Rails nested form fields_for doubled in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create a form where users can see a list of their friends and add or remove friends from lists (sort of like facebook's groups).  For the create list view, I can get the form working properly, but for the edit view I'm having trouble with check_box syntax and fields_for.

```
routes.rb
  resources :friendships
  resources :friend_lists

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :friend_lists
  has_many :flist_memberships, class_name: 'FlistMembership', foreign_key: 'member_id', dependent: :destroy
...
end

class FriendList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :flist_memberships
  has_many :members, through: :flist_memberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :flist_memberships, allow_destroy: true
end

class FlistMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :friend_list
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
end

class FriendListsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @friend_list = current_user.friend_lists.build
    @friends = current_user.friends.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @friend_list.flist_memberships.build
  end

  def create
    @friend_list = current_user.friend_lists.build(friend_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          if @friend_list.save
            flash[:success] = "Friends list created!"
            redirect_to friendships_path
          else
            render 'friend_lists/new'
          end
          }
      end
  end

  def edit
    @friend_list = FriendList.find(params[:id])
    @friends = current_user.friends
  end

  def update
    @friend_list = FriendList.find(params[:id])
    if @friend_list.update_attributes(friend_list_params)
      flash[:success] = "Friend list updated!"
      redirect_to friend_list_path(@friend_list)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def friend_list_params
    params.require(:friend_list).permit(:name, flist_memberships_attributes: [:id, :member_id, :friend_list_id])
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @friend_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Name for this friends list:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :flist_memberships do |m| %>
      <%= m.check_box :member_id, {}, friend.id %>
      <%= m.label :member_id, friend.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @friend_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Name for this friends list:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :flist_memberships do |m| %>
    <%= m.collection_check_boxes(:member_id, @friends.all, :id, :name) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb renders and saves the selected items correctly, but I can't figure out how to write the edit form so that it doesn't iterate through the collection once for each item in the collection (both with collection_check_boxes and the form as written in new.html.erb).  Trying

```
<%= f.fields_for :flist_memberships do |m| %>
  <%= m.check_box :id %>
  <%= m.label :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

in the edit form just passes the string "id" as params rather than pulling the id of each member in the collection, and I'm not sure how to pull the individual item's name/id without iterating over the collection, which goes back to the multiple renders problem.  I'm using cocoon elsewhere in the project, but for this I'd rather present the user a list of all options and allow them to check a box for each one, rather than having to manually add each item on the list.  If there is a way to do it with cocoon, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?